# Saving certain data into an array from a DBGrid

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-10-seattle

I would like to ask for help.

I have been tasked with saving FighterID into an array. This data will be used to make fighter 1 ,fight, fighter 2(the data has already been sorted in descending order according to wins they have).

I could only find ways to do this with 2D arrays, i would like tom use a 1 dimensional array.

I have no idea how to save a specific columns info into the array. I have tried the following and got the following error:

> [dcc32 Error] Presets.pas(53): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

Code:

```
procedure TPresetsForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    var I:integer;
    var s:string;
begin
    qry1.Close;
    qry1.sql.add('SELECT FighterName,Wins,Sponser FROM Preset_Fighters');
    qry1.Active := true;

    qry1.Open;
    tbl111.Sort:= 'Wins DESC' ;

    for I := 1 to 6 do
    begin
        Fightorder[I]:=(Presets.PresetsForm.dbgrd_info.Columns[0].FieldName:=('FighterID');
    end;
end;
```

I have no idea if this is the correct way to obtain the `FighterID` example (MT54).

All data is from MS Access, I hope I have provided enough information

Thanks for the help XD

Comment: `FighterID` does not seem to be part of your SQL statement

Comment: Please expand your code to show the `Flightorder` declaration

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
var
  Fightorder: array[1..6] of string;

procedure TPresetsForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  qry1.Close;
  qry1.Sql.Add('SELECT FighterName, Wins, Sponser FROM Preset_Fighters');
  qry1.Active := True;
  qry1.Open;
  for I := 1 to 6 do
  begin
    Fightorder[I] := qry1.Fields[0].AsString;
    qry1.Next;
  end;
end;
```

I think this will help you figure it out.

Comment: The correct code after some changes was   
``for I := 1 to 6 do
      begin
       Fightorder[I] := tbl111.Fields[0].AsString;
      tbl111.Next;
      end;``

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!